# Odd valued dimensional number impossible to build?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis, clifford-algebras

Using numbers of the form $$\alpha_1+\alpha_2e_1+\alpha_3e_2+...+\alpha_ne_{n-1}$$
where $\alpha_n\in\Bbb R$ and for all $a≠b, \alpha_a≠\alpha_b$ with $e_n^2=-1$, can these numbers exist for an odd *n*? I'm asking this question because if *n* is odd there will be at least one product of the form $e_ae_b$ that wouldn't be defined. Of course, for $n=1$, we have the Reals but then, we have $n=2, n=4, n=8, n=16$ respectively the Complexes, the Quaternions, the Octonions and Sedenions. Note that none of these values of n is odd and all are powers of 2.

Comment: Are you talking about these numbers being closed under multiplication?  Because otherwise, products of such numbers are perfectly defined in the clifford algebra--it's just that the product of two such numbers is not always another such number.

Comment: @Muphrid What do you mean by _closed under multiplication_?

Comment: Exactly what I said--that the product of two such numbers is another such number.  The product of two reals is real.  The product of two complex numbers is a complex number; the product of two quaternions is a quaternion.  Number systems that obey this property are said to be *closed*.  My point is that you can choose $n$ not a power of 2 and still get valid elements of a clifford algebra--such elements *exist*--but I think the question you *want* to ask is whether multiplication will be closed or not.

Comment: @moray95 "A set closed under an operation" is abstract algebra lingo for when you can combine two elements of the set with an operation, and the result is still in the set. For example, $\{1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$ is a subset of the quaternions which is closed under multiplication. So is the set of even integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of Clifford/geometric algebras (which we have been talking about recently), I can give you a crash course on how a *special case* of a real geometric algebra is built. Keep in mind that what I'm describing is a special case, and there are more possibilities.

Here is a brief introduction to why Clifford algebras for finite dimensional vector spaces always have dimension a power of $2$. I think the main prerequisite is that you need to understand what a basis is for a vector space.

Given a finite dimensional $\Bbb R$ vector space $V$,  find an orthonormal basis $e_1\dots e_n$ for the usual inner product (the dot product). Create a multiplication table for these elements using the following rules:

1. $e_ie_i^2=1$
2. $e_ie_j=-e_je_i$ for all $i\neq j$.

With just these two rules, and assuming that the $e_i$'s commute with all scalars, you can compute all products of $e_i$'s. For example,

$e_1e_2e_1=e_1(-e_1e_2)=-e_1e_1e_2=-e_2$

and $(e_1e_3)(e_2e_4)=e_1e_3e_2e_4=-e_1e_2e_3e_4$

and $e_2e_5e_1=-e_2e_1e_5=e_1e_2e_5$.

It's not hard to show that if you take *all* products of basis vectors whose subscripts are strictly increasing, that list of new things is a basis for a Clifford algebra $C\ell_{n,0}(\Bbb R)$. (The "empty" product of $e_i$'s is 1 by convention.) Being a basis means that everything in the algebra will be uniquely expressible as a sum of these things.

So for $n=1$, you just have one $e_1$, and along with the empty product $1$, your basis for the whole Clifford algebra is $\{1,e_1\}$, where $e_1^2=1$. (These are the split-complex numbers.)

For $n=2$, you would have $e_1$ and $e_2$, but you would also need the empty product  $1$, as well as $e_1e_2$ in the basis. So you see, this one has four elements.

For $n=3$, you start with $e_1,e_2,e_3$, and throw in $1,e_1e_2,e_1e_3,e_2e_3$ and also you don't forget to throw in $e_1e_2e_3$. This is a basis of 8 elements! For the 3-dimensional vector space.

If you count up how many basis elements are produced this way, you'll find that there are always $2^n$ elements, explaining part of the pattern you saw so far.

This departs from your pattern though: the octonions do not fit the Clifford algebra construction since all Clifford algebras are associative rings (and octions and sedenions are not).

Comment: What complex numbers and quaternions have in common is that they can be derived from spinors--even elements---of the 2d and 3d real clifford algebras.  You can look at the even subalgebras of an $N$-dimensional real clifford algebra to see how that is extended, and it's interesting to note the differences between that and the usual sequence from complex numbers to quaternions to octonions and so on.

Comment: @Muphrid Any suggestions for particularly lucid discussions of spinors from the algebraic point of view? I am always looking for more...

Comment: You know, I think Dorst, Fontijne, and Mann has a good discussion on the nature of orthogonal transformations in general.  They talk about "versors"--geometric products of invertible vectors--which unify rotations and reflections. Rotors, then, are just geometric products of an even number of vectors.  Most rotors are also unit ("special") spinors--in that the only requirement on a spinor is that it preserves grade under a bilinear sandwiching--but some special spinors are not rotors. It's a really good discussion on what all the terminology means and how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You may be intrested in [Hurwitz' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_%28normed_division_algebras%29).

A "simpler" proof that the dimension is always a power of two goes like this:

**Theorem.** If there is a continuous odd map $S^{n-1}\times S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$, then $n$ is a power of $2$.

Applying this theorem to the map $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{xy}{\Vert xy\Vert}$ (no zero divisors!) gives the desired result baout "dimensional numbers" (or rather division algebras).

The proof of the theorem itself can be done using homology and cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb F_2$. I won't go into details, see for example Ebbinghaus et. al., *Zahlen*, Springer.

Comment: Can you just explain this in simple words please, I'm just a high-school student so I can't understand anything about the article.

Comment: @moray95 D'oh, just read your comment - you won't understand anything I say about ochomology, either, I'm afraid ...

Comment: So as I understand, if n is odd, then the product of two numbers in form above won't have the n equal to the original number's ones. Is this it?